# Calling Django view does not execute the function when called more than once

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, expo

Spring function in Django Views is executed well when called once, but not executed when called twice. Any help would be appreciated.

**views.py**

The below is Spring function in views.py. **"spring: try starts"** is printed when the function is called once but nothing appears in terminal when the function is called for the second time.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def spring(request):
    try:
        print("spring: try starts")
        pc = seasonCheck("spring")
        return StreamingHttpResponse(gen("spring",pc), content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
    except Exception as ex:
        return HttpResponse(ex)
```

**seasonTest**

The below is where Spring function is called.

```
  function seasonTest(season) {    
        if (season == "spring") {
            setImg('http://localhost:8000/spring/');
        }
}
```

The function below is where SeasonTest is called. Whenever the user clicks the button, seasonTest has to be executed. As mentioned above, however, Spring function is not executed when the user clicks the button more than once.

```
function Self_season({ navigation, route, props }) {
   
    const [img_path, setImg] = useState('http://localhost:8000/spring/');
    return (
              <Image style={diagnoseStyle.video} source={{ uri: img_path }} /> 
              <View style={diagnoseStyle.button_container} activeOpacity={0.3}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => {        
                            seasonTest("spring"); -> Whenever the user clicks the button, seasonTest has to be executed. 
                        }}
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
});
```

Comment: Check the network tab in the browser. Are there multiple requests to `http://localhost:8000/spring/` shown there?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  No, I see only one Spring/ in the network tab when click the button. Spring/ is shown only once even if button is clicked more than once.

Comment: Then the issue is with your JavaScript code, not your Django code. It looks like you are using React here, correct? You will need to show more code for us to be able to help you. What library are you using to make the HTTP request?